# Why does the .isdigit() function return an error when I use it?

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to create a function that returns string numbers as "NUM" when the sentence is passed through my function, but I get an error. My code is as follows:

```
def number_normalise(sentence):
  for token in sentence:
    if sentence[token].isdigit():  # This is the part that returns the error.
      sentence[token] = "NUM"
    else:
      sentence[token]

  return sentence
```

For the third line of code I get an error saying that "list indices must be integers or slices, not str". I've tested the function separately and it should return a boolean number when it meets a word that is only  a number (e.g. "5", "1802"). Could somebody help me understand what is wrong with my code and how I can improve it?

Comment: what is the type of `sentence`? If it is a string or a list of strings you can simply reference each token with `token` rather than `sentence[token]`

Comment: The problem is sentence[token], that is not how do things in Python- token is (probably) not an integer. Doing token.isdigit() should be enough

Comment: For `hello123`, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sentence` is a list of strings and you are iterating over those strings. So, on line 3 you are actually trying to get a specific element from your list. But instead of integer i.e. `sentence[2]` you are passing a string i.e. `sentence["apple"]` which is wrong for obvious reasons.

I think you want to do:

```
def number_normalise(sentence: List[str]):
    for i, token in enumerate(sentence):
      if token.isdigit():  
         sentence[i] = "NUM"

    return sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what sentence variable is but I think you should write

```
...
if token.isdigit():
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the `sentence[token]` which is causing problem. `token` is probably a string while you should ask for the index of the element in `sentence`